# Import GDAL Error

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to import GDAL to run in 64-bit spyder and am getting the following error:
    import gdal
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-27bf4694dd2b>", line 1, in <module>
    import gdal

  File "C:\Users\Rdebbout\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn

  File "C:\Users\Rdebbout\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Users\Rdebbout\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 28, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)

 ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

I downloaded gdal as a wheel file from [gohlke's](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) website and then used pip install GDAL-1.11.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl.

Comment: Have you tried `conda install gdal` instead of an external build? https://anaconda.org/osgeo/gdal

Comment: yes I have with no luck.  Do you need to download GDAL core files before doing the conda install?

Comment: No, it should be self contained. Do you have the MS Visual C++ runtimes installed ([VC++ 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092) and perhaps [VC++ 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632))?

Comment: Yes. 2008 and 2010

Comment: Do you have a 32bit GDAL installed?  Note: please edit  your question with this and  previous info so it's all in one place.

Comment: @rickdebbout did you ever figure this problem out? ive been stuck for days on trying to properly install gdal

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with version 2.0. You can try installing a previous version 
conda install gdal=1.11.2
For more information see:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/400